# Geodesic radius of curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to compute the geodesic (or tangent) radius of curvature of the geodesic circle by using the below formula.

$\frac{1}{\rho_c}=\frac{\partial G/\partial S}{2\sqrt{E} G}$

where $s$ is the arc length parameter and $E$, $G$ are the coefficents of the first fundamental form.

Can you please tell me how to perfrom the $\partial G/\partial S$? Since $G=r_v\cdot r_v$ I am not sure how to derivate it with respect to arc length

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Geodesic (or tangent) curvature of geodesic "parallel" circles in geodesic polar coordinates is given ( for $ s = u $= constant lines, not $v$= constant ) by:

$ 1/ρ_c= \kappa_c=∂G/∂s/(2G). $

where s is the arc length parameter and  G is the coefficient of the first fundamental form.
You must choose your particular case parametrization next. For example in case of axis-symmetric cylindrical coordinates $G = r^2$ , where $d $ can be written for $ ∂$, constant Gauss curvature differential equation

$ ∂^2\sqrt G/∂s^2 + K \sqrt G=0 $ becomes  $ d^2r/ds^2 + K  r=0 $

etc. can be solved in terms of elliptic integrals.